# JavaScript break each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

```
function hellofunction(arrObj, val){
    $.each(arrObj,function(k,v){
        if(arrObj[k]["EMP_NO"] == val){
            return arrObj[k]["EMP_NAME"];
        }
    });
}

// Call function
var kaka = hellofunction(data["OUT_REC"], "roth_kakvey");

console.log("=====:"+kaka);
```

Output = "underfine"

Please help me, why it always output = "Underfine"?

Comment: `hellofunction` does not return anything ... which is the same as `return undefined`

Comment: and im pretty sure it doesnt return `underfine`...^^

Comment: `hellofunction` doesn't return anything. To break out of `each`, use `return false;` Assign the value to a variable and then return the variable from outside of the `each` **Code:** `function hellofunction(arrObj, val) {
    var value;
    $.each(arrObj, function (k, v) {
        if (arrObj[k]["EMP_NO"] == val) {
            value = arrObj[k]["EMP_NAME"];
            return false;
        }
    });

    return value;
}`

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(arrObj,function(k,v){
        if(arrObj[k]["EMP_NO"] == val){
            return arrObj[k]["EMP_NAME"];  
           // does not return from the hellofunction.
           // Instead it returns from the function(k,v) i.e. the callback to each
        }
    });
```

So to do this:

```
function hellofunction(arrObj, val){
    var empName;
    $.each(arrObj,function(k,v){
        if(arrObj[k]["EMP_NO"] == val){
            empName = arrObj[k]["EMP_NAME"];
            return false; //returning from callback, works like break statement
        }
    });
    return empName;
}
```